# What will be the costing if participant joins without video/audio to twilio room, initially?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

What will be the costing, if users initially joins with no audio/video to Twilio room?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The cost is the same no matter what a participant does in the room, it's just based on the number of participants in a room. You can see more [information on Programable Video pricing which is based on room type here](https://www.twilio.com/video/pricing).

Comment: from the link > Group room pricing is based on the amount of time your participants are connected in a room., that's mean if user connect with audio/video the cost will be the same even if user just connects with audio only or video only? or neither with both?

Comment: The cost will be the same no matter what. It's based on the number of participants, unrelated to whether or not they connect with audio only, video only, or both.

Comment: Well it should be consider while costing.